# Question on how to instantiate a class (unclear from Javadoc)

Tags: java

I am trying out ScalarDB. Unfortunately Java is not my strong point so I am struggling. In the example here

https://github.com/indetail-blockchain/getting-started-with-scalardb#initialize-distributedtransactionmanager

The docs are at https://scalar-labs.github.io/scalardb/javadoc/

1. Q1: The DistributedTransactionManager is created by

   `DistributedTransactionManager transaction = injector.getInstance(TransactionModule.class);`

   But How can `TransactionModile.class` be assigned like this as from the docs I don't see any relationship between the two classes.
2. Q 2
   It seems I need an instance of `DistributedTransactionManager` to start transactions. `DistributedTransactionManager` is an interface implemented by `TransactionService`. But the constructor of `TransactionService` takes instance of `DistributedTransactionManager`. How is this getting resolved? Isn't it cyclic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the getting started doc.

https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#store--retrieve-data-with-transaction-service

As it says, this is the way to start a transaction.

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TransactionModule(new DatabaseConfig(props)));
TransactionService service = injector.getInstance(TransactionService.class);
DistributedTransaction tx = service.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q1.  I don't see any relationship between the two classes.

That is how Guice works. In xxxModule class bindings will be defined and the variables will be replaced by those bindings. For example in your case TransactionModule has a configure method in which bindings are defined as

```
@Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(DistributedTransactionManager.class).to(ConsensusCommitManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(DistributedStorage.class).to(config.getStorageClass()).in(Singleton.class);
  }
```

So, if getInstace(TransactionModule ) is assigned to DistributedTransactionManager then instance of ConsensusCommitManager will be replaced.

> Q2.  How is this getting resolved? Isn't it cyclic?

Again guice is different here. It uses [just in time bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings) and it created no constructor object first and inject parameters and also it understands that DistributedTransactionManager  will never be an instance of TransactionService through bindings.

I know for spring users it will be a bit confusing concept. But that is how it works.